# CURL php always return TRUE?

Tags: php, curl

Curl php always `curl_exec()` return TRUE  ?
I make CURL Php and always TRUE, although no internet? what's wrong with the following coding?

```
$POST = array(
        'salesdata' => json_encode($sales_data)
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://accordpos.skyware.systems/api");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($POST));

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
$conn = $this->is_connected();
$this->db->trans_begin();

$this->sync_model->sales_sync($sales);

if(($server_output === false) ||($conn == 0))
{
    echo "Error Number:".curl_errno($ch)."<br>";
    echo "Error String:".curl_error($ch);
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
else {
    $this->db->trans_commit();
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Where does your code show that it returns `TRUE`? All you show is that it doesn't return `FALSE`. That means it succeeded and returned a string.

Comment: Try echoing `$server_output` in the `else` block to see what it returned.